# 5 items per row, auto-resize items in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this at the moment:

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  background: blue;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
  <div class="item">F</div>
  <div class="item">G</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is have 5 items per row in a flexbox. Currently they don't appear because they don't have a set width/height, which leads me to my next question. Is it possible to auto-resize the items in order for 5 of them to fit per row?

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say five when there's seven?

Comment: The two extra should just go on a new line. I added them just to check if the CSS worked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4ho17w9m/1/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are right in giving a `flex-basis: 20%` but you have to adjust for the 4px margin on each *flex item* for it to *wrap* properly.

---

#### Equal Width Flex items in the last row

Use `flex: 0 1 calc(20% - 8px)` - this means the item won't grow beyond 20% of width (adjusting for margin) and can shrink based on the container width. See demo below:

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px; /* height given for illustration */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(20% - 8px); /* <-- adjusting for margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another approach is a bit *hacky* - you can keep `flex-grow` set to one and `flex-basis: calc(20% - 4px)` using `flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 4px)`, and use a *pseudo element* that fills the remaining space:

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px; /* height given for illustration */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 8px); /* <-- adjusting for margin */
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex: 999; /* grow by a large number */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't have the ***n item per row*** requirement then you can refer this:

- [Unordered list that acts like grid-auto-flow dense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556049/unordered-list-that-acts-like-grid-auto-flow-dense/55556507#55556507)

---

#### Flex items in last row expands to fill the available space

If in a row you have less than 5 items and you want them to fill in the remaining space use `flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 8px)` (note that `flex-grow` is set to 1 here so that the *flex items* in the last rows *expand to fill the remaining space*):

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;  /* height given for illustration */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background: blue;
  margin: 4px;
  flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 8px);  /* <-- adjusting for margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

try below css for five items in each row.

```css
.container {
  background: gray none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}

.item {
  background: blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
  flex: 1 1 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any way to keep the second row items the same width/height as the first row's items?

Comment: just noticed.. in this answer it will not work as `flex-basis` is 18%... you will have some space after the fifth div at the end of the row :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this on a WordPress project, where I have to list articles by categories, nested in columns. I just wrote some css for the responsive layout, so as you decrease the browser width, there are less elements in a row.

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 calc(20% - 20px);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .item {
    flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 20px)
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .item {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 20px)
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .item {
    flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 20px)
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .item {
    flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 20px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></br><a>Link2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></br><a>Link2</a></br><a>Link3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></br><a>Link2</a></br><a>Link3</a></br><a>Link4</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></br><a>Link2</a></br><a>Link3</a></br><a>Link4</a></br><a>Link5</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a>Link1</a></br><a>Link2</a></br><a>Link3</a></br><a>Link4</a></br><a>Link5</a></br><a>Link6</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9f955jk2/3/
You have to be aware of margins or paddings, that's why I setted the width to 18%
You can set them to 20% (100%/5 items per row) if you will remove all the margins and paddings.
Also don't forget that border will also take some space.
The container should have 100%, otherwise you have to divide the width by 5 and specify it in pixel for each item and not in %

```
 .container {
      width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: So, all that you had to do in your jsfiddle was to decrease the value   flex-basis: 18%;