# Generating FlexBox layout with Button

Tags: ios, swift, flexbox

How can generate the flexbox layout with button please check the attach image. Any library available? Or can make with collectionView.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView

Comment: https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: flexbox option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556049/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use a collection view, and implement this delegate function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var str: String = data[indexPath.row]
    let font: UIFont = /*Your Font*/
    let size: CGSize = str.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])

    return CGSize(width: size.width + 39, height: 45)
```