# FlexBox in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Good day.
I am trying to release dynamic placement of elements based on their size. Works in an empty project, but sometimes does not show the entire text. And in a working project, a maximum of 2-3 elements are displayed. Maybe I'm on the wrong path. Please tell me in which direction to look.
I thought to use UICollectionView and UIViewRepresentable but couldn't figure out exactly how. There were examples on the Internet, but there was a common grid and the columns had the same width. And I just need to pave elements of different widths all the space from left to right line by line.

```
struct CustomFlexBoxView<Content> : View where Content: View {
    let alignment: Alignment
    let spacing: CGFloat
    let content: [Content]
    @State private var sizeBody: CGSize? = nil
    @State private var sizeItems: [Int:CGSize] = [:]
    init(alignment: Alignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat = 0, content: [Content]) {
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { (geo) in
            if let sizeBody = self.sizeBody {
                self.contentView(sizeBody: sizeBody)
            }
            else {
                self.contentFirstView
                    .onAppear {
                        self.sizeBody = geo.frame(in: .global).size
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    private var contentFirstView: some View {
        let items = self.content
        return VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< items.count) { (index) in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    items[index]
                }
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { (geo) in
                        Color.clear.onAppear {
                            self.sizeItems[index] = geo.frame(in: .global).size
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
    private func contentView(sizeBody: CGSize) -> some View {
        let items = self.content
        var rowWidth: CGFloat = 0
        var rowItems: [Content] = []
        var rows: [AnyView] = []
        for index in 0 ..< items.count {
            if let size = self.sizeItems[index] {
                if rowWidth + size.width + self.spacing <= sizeBody.width {
                    let addSpacing = (rowItems.isEmpty ? 0 : self.spacing)
                    rowItems.append(items[index])
                    rowWidth = rowWidth + size.width  + addSpacing
                }
                else {
                    if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
                        rows.append(
                            AnyView(
                                self.createRow(items: rowItems)
                            )
                        )
                        rowWidth = 0
                        rowItems = []
                    }
                    rowWidth = size.width
                    rowItems = [ items[index] ]
                }
            }
            else {
                if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
                    rows.append(
                        AnyView(
                            self.createRow(items: rowItems)
                        )
                    )
                    rowWidth = 0
                    rowItems = []
                }
                rows.append(AnyView(items[index]))
            }
        }
        if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
            rows.append(
                AnyView(
                    self.createRow(items: rowItems)
                )
            )
            rowWidth = 0
            rowItems = []
        }
        return AnyView (
            VStack(alignment: self.alignment.horizontal, spacing: self.spacing) {
                ForEach(0 ..< rows.count) { ind in
                    rows[ind]
                }
            }
        )
    }
    private func createRow(items: [Content]) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: self.alignment.vertical, spacing: self.spacing) { [items] in
            ForEach(0 ..< items.count) { ind in
                items[ind]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On an empty project everything works, in the working one the first 2-3 elements are displayed.:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [Int] = [
        113, 2, 2342343, 234, 234234234234324, 3,
        45345435345345, 545, 34, 4, 345345345, 45345, 5, 5
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            CustomFlexBoxView(
                alignment: .topLeading,
                spacing: 10,
                content: self.data.map { TestText(text: "\($0)") }
            )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
struct TestText : View {
    let text: String
    @State private var color: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.text)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize()
            .background(self.color ? Color.orange : Color.gray)
            .foregroundColor(self.color ? Color.green : Color.black)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.color.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

But if you add more elements, then for some reason the total size of the CustomFlexBoxView is not estimated correctly:

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
            CustomFlexBoxView(
                alignment: .topLeading,
                spacing: 10,
                content: self.data.map { TestText(text: "\($0)") }
            )
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question with a minimal/reproducible example and some information about what you're expecting to see vs what you are seeing with your current code? Reading your question, I'm unclear on what to be looking for (or how to test it)

Comment: @jnpdx, updated description

Comment: I'd love to see a `ContentView` with the sample data in it to try running, too (rather than expecting people here to set up their own sample project). This might have more to do with just putting a modifier on your `Text` than changing your algorithm.

Comment: @jnpdx, added ContentView

Comment: did not take into account spacing, in the empty example everything worked, but in the working one it did not. I will try to find the minimum version of the project with the problem and update the code.

Comment: @jnpdx, problem in CustomFlexBoxView size

Comment: I would like something similar but on SwiftUI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275455/generating-flexbox-layout-with-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made solutions for my project, but I'm not sure if this will always work.

```
struct CustomFlexBoxView<Item, Content> : View where Item: Hashable, Content: View {
    let alignment: Alignment
    let spacing: CGFloat
    let items: [Item]
    let content: (Int) -> Content
    
    @State private var sizeBody: CGSize? = nil
    @State private var widthItems: [Item: CGFloat] = [:]
    
    init(alignment: Alignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat = 0, items: [Item], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.items = items
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        self.contentView
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: self.alignment)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { (geo) in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        self.sizeBody = geo.frame(in: .global).size
                    }
                }
            )
    }
    
    private var contentView: some View {
        VStack(alignment: self.alignment.horizontal, spacing: self.spacing) {
            ForEach(self.rowsIndices, id: \.self) { (row) in
                self.createRow(indices: row)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createRow(indices: [Int]) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: self.alignment.vertical, spacing: self.spacing) {
            ForEach(indices, id: \.self) { (index) in
                Group {
                    self.content(index)
                }
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { (geo) in
                        Color.clear.onAppear {
                            self.widthItems[self.items[index]] = geo.frame(in: .global).size.width
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var rowsIndices: [[Int]] {
        guard let widthBody = self.sizeBody?.width else {
            return self.items.indices.map { [ $0 ] }
        }
        var rowWidth: CGFloat = 0
        var rowItems: [Int] = []
        var rows: [[Int]] = []
        for index in 0 ..< items.count {
            if  let widthItem = self.widthItems[self.items[index]] {
                let rowWidthNext = rowWidth + widthItem + (rowItems.isEmpty ? 0 : self.spacing)
                if rowWidthNext <= widthBody {
                    rowItems.append(index)
                    rowWidth = rowWidthNext
                }
                else {
                    if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
                        rows.append(rowItems)
                        rowWidth = 0
                        rowItems = []
                    }
                    rowWidth = widthItem
                    rowItems = [ index ]
                }
            }
            else {
                if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
                    rows.append(rowItems)
                    rowWidth = 0
                    rowItems = []
                }
                rows.append([ index ])
            }
        }
        if rowItems.isEmpty == false {
            rows.append(rowItems)
            rowWidth = 0
            rowItems = []
        }
        return rows
    }
}
```

Comment: This used to work quite well however I've noticed that with iOS 17 the very first time CustomFlexBoxView is shown all of my items are shown one by one and each occupying an entire row, even there is more space available.

Comment: @Niklas, I have a test example displayed normally on 12 mini iOS 17.2.1. Maybe there are some additional conditions?

Comment: Maybe. I found https://github.com/berbschloe/FlexView which works quite well, at least for now, for my use case