# CSS - Three containers per row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

I have three left floated containers per row on my website with 33% width and I would like to provide the first of the new row with the attribute clear: both, because there are 12 containers.

Is there an easier way to determine the selector?
Here is my approach:

```
.container:nth-of-type(4), .container:nth-of-type(7), .container:nth-of-type(10) {
    clear: both;
}
```

I've also tried something with "3n", but it I didn't work for me...

I know it doesn't work... but is there something like this?

```
.container:nth-of-type(4,7,10) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Or are there better approaches? Every answer is appreciated, thanks.

```css
.container {
  width: calc((100% - 120px)/3); /* calc because of the padding */
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.container:nth-of-child(4), .container:nth-of-child(7), .container:nth-of-child(10) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: 4,7 and 10 should be represented with 3n+1 I think

Comment: @syno checkout my answer will solve your issue

Comment: You should really think about converting to using something other than floats - they shouldn't be needed now we have css3

Comment: possible guidance using css flexboxes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504320/5-items-per-row-auto-resize-items-in-flexbox/39504642#39504642) - its 5 items in a row there, you can modify it for your use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nth-of-type` pseudoselector works like an algebraic equation. If you use `nth-of-type(3n)`, it's going to target the 0th, 3rd, 6th, etc. elements. You need to add 1, making it `nth-of-type(3n+1)` to target the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc.

```css
.container {
  width: calc((100% - 130px)/3); /* calc because of the padding */
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.container:nth-of-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
.container:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:nth-of-type(3n+4)`, but with `clear:both` the selected container will be the only one in the row. Use `clear: left` instead.