# How to start a new line with a particular item with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

This is a very simple exercise but I can't seem to find a neat way to solve it (just started learning about HTML and CSS).

[image: 5 blocks in a row]

I need the 5th block ("bloque 5") in red to be under the other four using Flexbox.
The result should be:

[image: 4 blocks in a row and 1 in another row]

Could somebody help me with this, please? This is what I have so far:

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.contenidor {
  width: 760px;
  display: flex;
}

div[class*=element] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px 30px 5px 2px;
}

.element5 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenidor">
  <div class="element1">bloque 1</div>
  <div class="element2">bloque 2</div>
  <div class="element3">bloque 3</div>
  <div class="element4">bloque 4</div>
  <div class="element5">bloque 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *gist* of having *n items in a row* with flexbox is that *padding* and *margin* must also be considered because you are *wrapping* the flexbox. I made the following changes in your code:

- for wrapping a flexbox, you need to give `flex-wrap: wrap` on the *flexbox container*,
- to get 4 items per row, you can use `flex-basis` as 25% and adjust for the margin using `calc`,
- to get the rows with less that 4 items *fill the available space*, you can consider `flex-grow: 1` on the *flex items* too,
- also consider adding `box-sizing: border-box` on the `element*` so that the *padding* is included in the *width* (and therefore in `flex-basis`)

You can find a similar question here: [*`arranging 5 items in a row`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504320/5-items-per-row-auto-resize-items-in-flexbox/39504642#39504642). See demo below:

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.contenidor {
  width: 760px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrapping flexbox */
}

div[class*=element] {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  padding: 2px 30px 5px 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* adjusts for padding */
  flex-grow: 1; /* expand to fill remaining space */
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 10px); /* 4 items per row, adjust for the 5px margin */
}

.element5 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenidor">
  <div class="element1">bloque 1</div>
  <div class="element2">bloque 2</div>
  <div class="element3">bloque 3</div>
  <div class="element4">bloque 4</div>
  <div class="element5">bloque 5</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is really no reason to do something like this `div[class*=element]` just specify class with a dot `div.element`
2. one of the reason your code doesn't work is that you're missing box-sizing.
   Adding padding and margin in this way will grow your children over the wanted size.
3. When working with flex use the flex parameters, it will really simplify your work.

You can see a good tutorial for how to use flex-box here
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here is a simple way to do it.

```css
 div {
      border: 1px solid black;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: stretch;
    }
    
    .child {
      flex: 1 0 25%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">I am one</div>
      <div class="child">I am two</div>
      <div class="child">I am three</div>
      <div class="child">I am four</div>
      <div class="child">I am five</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section > div {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

section > div:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
  1
  </div>
  <div>
  2
  </div>
  <div>
  3
  </div>
  <div>
  4
  </div>
  <div>
  5
  </div>
</section>
```