# Control item count in a row with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to show 4 items in 1st row as it is, but only 3 in second line, and then 4 in 3rd line and 3 in 4th line and so on...

I have achieved this by `nth-child` but code was too much and not flexible and expandable.

Is it possible by flex? or grid?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: All items must be the same size? Will something like this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/jxt5cm7u/2/

Comment: So... where do you want to define how many items per line are shown? The `nth-child` syntax allows you to do that programmatically. Otherwise, you could use a `data-` attribute in the HTML and use an attribute selector in CSS to key off of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to consider one rule like below:

```
 /*7 = 4 (1st row) + 3 (2nd row) and 5 = 1st element in 2nd row (4 + 1)*/
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n + 5) {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  flex-grow:0;
}
```

The trick is to make one element bigger to trigger the wrap then rely on `flex-grow` to fill the space.

Full code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n + 5) {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  flex-grow:0;
}

p {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div><div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible by flex? or grid?

Here is a solution using ***grid*** which is easier to construct:

- consider a 12-column grid layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)`,
- place each `grid-item` into 4 columns by using `grid-column: span 3`,
- 7 `grid-item`s are repeating in a pattern; which means every even row has 3 items with *nth-child* indices `7n`, `7n - 1` and `7n - 2`.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid; /* grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); /* 12-column layout */
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  grid-column: span 3; /* 4 items in a row */
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 2),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 1),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n) { /* even row */
  grid-column: span 4; /* 3 items in the even row */
}

p {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

---

#### Flexbox solution

And I'd use just about the same *nth-child* logic in the case of a flexbox and the only change in your code would be the below:

```
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 2),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 1),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n) { /* even row */
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-wrapper .grid-item {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* ADDED THESE */
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 2),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n - 1),
.grid-wrapper .grid-item:nth-child(7n) { /* even row */
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>Grid Item</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

---

On a separate note, if you interested in having *n items in a row* with flexboxes, the below answers may give you more information:

- [5 items per row, auto-resize items in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504320)
- [How to start a new line with a particular item with Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791036)