# Having trouble getting images to wrap with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For some reason I cannot get these images to wrap. They overflow past the point of the width I made for my container. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong by putting paragraphs under each image and that's affecting it?

For the images to wrap so I can have 3 on top and 2 right below the 3, each with their title centered right under the image.

```css
.block2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.pics {
  display: flex;
}

.pics img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pics p {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2">
  <div class="text2">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h1>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="pics">
    <img src="images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berryblitz">
    <p>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</p>
    <img src="images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="spicedrum">
    <p>Spiced Rum Tea</p>
    <img src="images/img-donut.jpg" alt="donut">
    <p>Seasonal Donuts</p>
    <img src="images/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" alt="myrtle">
    <p>Myrtle Ave Tea</p>
    <img src="images/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" alt="bedford">
    <p>Bedford Bizarre Tea</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `flex-wrap:wrap;` directly in your `.pics` class.

Comment: I might add, if this doesn't solve your problem, can you be more specific about the nature of it? I am trying it on a fiddle, but the images don't come up so I can't see their specific alignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea of flex, is that there is a flex container, and inside that container are the flex items.

[image]

[image]

By default, a flex container will always try to fit all of its items into one line. So that is what is happening to your content right now. All of your `img` and  `p` elements are direct children of the flex container, so it is fitting them on one line.

If you want them to wrap to a second line, you can set `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your flex container's (`.pics`) CSS. This will start to wrap your elements. However this still won't result in the behaviour you want.

Right now, each `img` and `p` is a direct child of the flex container, if you want an `img` and a `p` to be moved together within the flex container, you will need to group them together, possibly in something like a `div`.

```
 <div class="pics">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="berryblitz">
    <p>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</p>
  </div>
   ...
<div>
```

Now, at least the paragraph and image will be together. You can now set any other styling you want for each item, such as centering, on the item (`.pic`).

I recommend checking out [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide to flex box for more details. Hopefully this lead you in the right direction, but there are many other ways to utilize flex as well!

Answer (score 1):

So you need to have three items in the first row and two in the row below:

- with flexbox you need to have a wrapper for the image and the description to start with (using `figure` to wrap the image and description here),
- also you should be giving `flex-wrap: wrap` on the *flex container* and not on the *flex item*,
- now you can use `flex-basis` or `width` (say `flex-basis: 33.33%`) for the *wrapping flexbox* to have 3 items per row

See demo below with comments inline:

```css
.block2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}

.pics {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrapping flexbox */
}

.pics figure {
  margin: 0; /* reset default margin of figure */
  margin: 10px; /* space between flex items */
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 20px); /* 3 items in a row - adjust for the 10px margin on each side */
}

.pics img {
  display: block;
  height: 100px; /* height of each row */
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* fit as cover maintaining aspect ratio */
}

figcaption {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2">
  <div class="text2">
    <h2>Tea of the Month</h2>
    <h1>What's Steeping at The Tea Cozy?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="pics">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
      <figcaption>
        Fall Berry Blitz Tea
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
      <figcaption>
        Spiced Rum Tea
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
      <figcaption>
        Seasonal Donuts
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
      <figcaption>
        Myrtle Ave Tea
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
      <figcaption>
        Bedford Bizarre Tea
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For having *n items in a row* with flexboxes, the below answers may give you more information:

- [5 items per row, auto-resize items in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504320)
- [How to start a new line with a particular item with Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791036)