# Flex box - wrap a row of 4 elements on to 2 lines but also is responsive when the screen is pinched

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to wrap a row of 4 elements on to 2 rows, see screenshot, but I want them to also be responsive when the screen is pinched or the resolution is different, I can't figure it out. see code.

```
.cats {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    gap: 25px;
}

.cat {
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the screenshot on and the html too please? Ta.

Comment: "*I want them to also be responsive when...*" - in what way, at what screen-sizes or resolutions, should the layout shift?

Comment: It looks like I've sorted it, I used this example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159909/how-can-i-place-these-images-into-2-rows-of-4-pictures-each-using-flexbox